# Python SQL Pandas - Cannot import dataframe larger than 27650 rows into database

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I am trying to import a large csv file (5 million rows) into a local MySQL database using the code below:

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine


engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://[username]:[password]@[host]:[port]/[schema]', echo=False)
    df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/[user]/Documents/Sales_Records.csv')
    df = df.head(27650)
    df.to_sql(con= engine, name='data', if_exists='replace', chunksize = 50000)
```

If I execute this code it works so long as df.head([row limit]) is less than 27650. However, as soon as I increase this row limit by just a single row, the import fails and now data is transferred to MySQL. Does anyone know why this would happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas DataFrame should have no memory limit except for your local machine's memory. So I think it's because your machine is running out of memory. You can use **memory_profiler**, a Python library I like to use to check real-time memory usage. More info can be found at the docs here: https://pypi.org/project/memory-profiler/

You should never read big files in one go as it's a single point of failure and also slow. Load the data into the database in chunks, like how they did in this post: https://soprasteriaanalytics.se/2020/10/22/working-with-large-csv-files-in-pandas-create-a-sql-database-by-reading-files-in-chunks/